# Why only ABE is used in ABAC

Tags: rsa, public-key, abe

Why ABAC access control model uses ABE not RSA or any other public key cryptography? Moreover what is the relation of ABAC with public key cryptography (ABE/RSA)?

Comment: This might be related: [What paradigm does ABE, KP-ABE and CP-ABE fall into](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/42659/13022)